# Ant, Maven and Jdeveloper SOA Extension

Tags: maven-2, ant, soa, oracle11g, jdeveloper

We are in the middle of a large Java EE project/programme. Up to this point, we've been using Eclipse and Maven for our development. The appserver we are targeting is WebLogic (Oracle, these days).
It has been decided we are going to start using Oracle Business Rules (Part of Oracle SOA Suite 11g). Development for Soa Suite is confined to JDeveloper. It has some nice ant scripts to build and deploy SOA Composites (which is how rules are packaged and deployed).
I have been tasked with getting these ant scripts to run from maven using antrun, and I've gotten some of the way, but not all...
My main question is: has anyone succeeded doing this? (Has anyone even attempted..? Can't really find anything googling...)

Below is the relevant part of my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <property name="oracle.home" value="C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper"/>
            <property name="oracle.soa.mgmt.home" value="C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper"/>
            <property name="common.components.home" value="C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common"/>
            <property name="env.JAVA_HOME" value="${java.home}"/>
            <property name="env.PWD" value="."/>
            <ant antfile="${oracle.home}\bin\ant-sca-compile.xml"/>
          </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Maven is run from the project dir, outside the Oracle/Middleware tree. This almost works...
Actually, it gives the following result:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building BilagorReglerSCA
[INFO]    task-segment: [compile]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] [compiler:compile]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [antrun:run {execution: default}]
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:

scac:
Validating composite "C:\JDeveloper\mywork\BilagorReglerSCA\BilagorRegler\composite.xml"
     [scac] oracle.fabric.common.wsdl.XSDException: Error loading schema from file:/C:/JDeveloper/mywork/BilagorReglerSCA/BilagorRegler/BilagorRegler_DecisionService.wsdl [Cause=Error in getting XML input stream: oramds:/soa/shared/rules/BpelProcess.xsd: oracle.mds.exception.MDSException: MDS-00054: Filen som ska laddas oramds:/soa/shared/rules/BpelProcess.xsd finns inte.]
     [scac]     at oracle.fabric.common.wsdl.SchemaBuilder.loadEmbeddedSchemas(SchemaBuilder.java:496)
     [scac]     at oracle.fabric.common.wsdl.SchemaBuilder.loadSchemasFromWSDL(SchemaBuilder.java:365)
...
```

The phrase "Filen som ska laddas oramds:/soa/shared/rules/BpelProcess.xsd finns inte." means the "file you are trying to load does not exist" (why does my client insist on installing Swedish language version of Windows, rather than international?).
ant-sca-compile.xml contains numerous import statements similar to this:

```
     <fileset dir="${common.components.home}/modules">
        ...
        <include name="oracle.mds_11.1.1/oramds.jar"/>
```

I assume oramds.jar is needed to process oramds-URL:s, which are used in the WSDS/XSD:s JDeveloper generates.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: typo - <proptery name="common.components.home" ... <property name="common.components.home"

Comment: Also a less harmful and more humorous Freudian typo - Actually, it gives the folowing reslut: ... Actually, it gives the following result:

Comment: Interesting, JDeveloper passes it off as correct pom.xml, highlighting and all - didn't solve the problem though, still get the second build error...

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I eventually got a chance to sit down with an ace Oracle consultant and get this to work.

This is what we came up with:

```
<properties>
    <oracle.fmw.soa.home>C:/Oracle/Middleware</oracle.fmw.soa.home>
    <!-- this is relative reference to JDK / Jrockit from ant-sca-compile|*.xml. For jdev it is ../../, for Soa Suite: TBD. -->
    <env.JAVA_HOME>../../jdk160_24</env.JAVA_HOME>
    <!-- For real server with Soa Suite installed use: Oracle_SOA1, for devenv use jdeveloper -->
    <oracle.fmw.productName>jdeveloper</oracle.fmw.productName>
    <antOutputDir>deploy</antOutputDir>
    <mvnOutputDir>target</mvnOutputDir>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sca-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property name="scac.input" value="${basedir}/composite.xml" />
                            <property name="scac.application.home" value="${basedir}/.." />
                            <property name="oracle.home" value="${oracle.fmw.soa.home}/${oracle.fmw.productName}" />
                            <ant
                                antfile="${oracle.fmw.soa.home}/${oracle.fmw.productName}/bin/ant-sca-compile.xml"
                                dir="${oracle.fmw.soa.home}/${oracle.fmw.productName}/bin/"
                                target="scac" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>sca-package</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target name="package">
                            <property name="build.compiler" value="extJavac" />
                            <property name="compositeName" value="${project.artifactId}" />
                            <property name="compositeDir" value="${basedir}" />
                            <property name="revision" value="${project.version}" />
                            <property name="scac.application.home" value="${basedir}/.." />
                            <property name="oracle.home" value="${oracle.fmw.soa.home}/${oracle.fmw.productName}" />
                            <property name="antOutputFile" value="sca_${project.artifactId}_rev${project.version}.jar" />
                            <property name="mvnOutputFile" value="${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar" />
                            <ant
                                antfile="${oracle.fmw.soa.home}/${oracle.fmw.productName}/bin/ant-sca-package.xml"
                                dir="${oracle.fmw.soa.home}/${oracle.fmw.productName}/bin"
                                target="package" />
                            <copy tofile="${mvnOutputDir}/${mvnOutputFile}" file="${antOutputDir}/${antOutputFile}" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>sca-deploy</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target name="deploy">
                            <property name="serverURL" value="${weblogic.serverURL}" />
                            <property name="user" value="${weblogic.user}" />
                            <property name="password" value="${weblogic.password}" />
                            <property name="sarLocation" value="${basedir}/deploy/sca_${project.artifactId}_rev${project.version}.jar" />
                            <property name="overwrite" value="true" />
                            <property name="forceDefault" value="true" />
                            <property name="partition" value="default" />
                            <property name="oracle.home" value="${oracle.fmw.soa.home}/${oracle.fmw.productName}" />
                            <ant
                                antfile="${oracle.fmw.soa.home}/${oracle.fmw.productName}/bin/ant-sca-deploy.xml"
                                dir="${oracle.fmw.soa.home}/${oracle.fmw.productName}/bin"
                                target="deploy" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>sca-test</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property name="jndi.properties.input" value="${basedir}/sca-test.jndi.properties" />
                            <property name="scatest.input" value="scatestinput" />
                            <property name="scatest.format" value="junit" />
                            <property name="scatest.result" value="reports" />
                            <property name="oracle.home" value="${oracle.fmw.soa.home}/${oracle.fmw.productName}" />
                            <ant
                                antfile="${oracle.fmw.soa.home}/${oracle.fmw.productName}/bin/ant-sca-test.xml"
                                dir="${oracle.fmw.soa.home}/${oracle.fmw.productName}/bin"
                                target="test" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note, both different sets of properties and parameters to the ant-tag than what I was originally attempting with.

To run on a CI-server, you obviously need a local install of JDeveloper or SOA Suite. `weblogic.serverURL`, `weblogic.user` and `weblogic.password` needs to be set to your corresponding environment (I use profiles for local/dev/tst/etc...).

Other than that, it works like a charm...

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Maven + Oracle SOA build scripts but generally when using any of the Oracle deployment tools (ADF, SOA, etc) you will need to have either an Oracle SOA Home or a JDev home (with the SCA extension) on the same machine that the build is running on. You'll need to set the Ant environment variables correctly e.g. oracle.home and common.components.home etc

Answer (score 0):

Use **ant-sca-package.xml** (not **ant-sca-compile.xml**):

```
<ant antfile="ant-sca-package.xml" dir="${env.BEA_HOME}/jdeveloper/bin">
  <property name="compositeDir" value="@{compositeDir}" />
  <property name="compositeName" value="@{compositeName}" />
  <property name="revision" value="${deploy.revision}" />
</ant>
```